# SQL Query without temp table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have below 2 Tables I need to get output witout temp tables

```
WorkItem

ItemID  ItemName Status
1      xyz       3
2      abc       3
3      MNO       2

WorkItemTrack

TrackID  ItemID  Status
1       1        1
2       1        2
3       1        3
4       2        1
5       2        2
6       3        1
7       3        2
```

This is my Query

```
select ItemName, WorkItem.Status from WorkItem Inner join WorkItemTrack ON WorkItem.ItemID=WorkItemTrack.ItemID
where WorkItemTrack.Status=2
```

& this my output

```
  ItemName Status
  XYZ       3
  ABC       3
  MNO       2
```

But I need output for only MNO with status 2

ie

```
 ItemName Status 
  MNO       2
```

how to do without using temp tables

Comment: The `Status` on both the `WorkItem` and the `WorkItemTrack` is confusing - which one do you want to filter on? Should they get joined as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either do

```
select ItemName, WorkItem.Status from WorkItem 
Inner join WorkItemTrack ON WorkItem.ItemID=WorkItemTrack.ItemID 
where WorkItemTrack.Status=2 and WorkItem.Status=2
```

or

```
select * from 
  (select ItemName, WorkItem.Status as status from WorkItem 
   Inner join WorkItemTrack ON WorkItem.ItemID=WorkItemTrack.ItemID 
    where WorkItemTrack.Status=2) 
where status=2
```

(if you need to get more complex later and want to do other things with the initial results)

Answer (score 1):

This will equally work

```
Select x.ItemName,x.Status
From (Select * from WorkItem where Status = 2) x
Join (Select ItemID from WorkItemTrack where Status = 2) y
on x.ItemID=y.ItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.ItemName, i.Status
from WorkItem i
inner join WorkItemTrack t ON i.ItemID = t.ItemID
where t.Status = 2
AND i.Status = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous, but this may be what you want:

```
SELECT ItemName, wi.Status
FROM WorkItem AS wi
JOIN WorkItemTrack AS wit ON (wi.ItemID=wit.ItemID) AND (wi.Status=wit.Status)
WHERE wit.Status=2
```

Or maybe

```
SELECT ItemName, wi.Status
FROM WorkItem AS wi
JOIN WorkItemTrack AS wit ON (wi.ItemID=wit.ItemID) AND (wit.Status=2)
WHERE wi.Status=2
```

Answer (score 0):

use one more `join` option

```
select a.ItemName, a.Status from WorkItem a Inner join worktrack b ON a.ItemID=b.ItemID and a.status=b.status where b.Status=2
```

or

else distinct

```
select  distinct ItemName, WorkItem.Status from WorkItem inner join worktrack ON WorkItem.ItemID=worktrack.ItemID where workitem.Status=2
```

or

else  row num

```
select  top 1 * from (select row_number() over (partition by workitem.status order by workitem.status ) as rownum , 
ItemName, WorkItem.Status from WorkItem inner join worktrack ON WorkItem.ItemID=worktrack.ItemID
where worktrack.status=2) a 
where a.rownum=1
```